# Role based access control in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

What are the elastic search versions will support security features like role based access control ??

I am using elastic search only as a document store (no kibana or logstash), can we achieve role based access ?

If yes, how to create users and provide read/write role for it ?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you read the [X-pack](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack) docs for the same.

This is not the exact answer but I am new to the elastic as well.

I would recommend using ELK stack for getting the access control.